# My android studio preview waiting for build to finish forever

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

My android studio 3.6 cannot see the preview. I have tried it on both windows and macos as shown below. Before updating to 3.6, everything used normally

[image: screenshot of As]

Comment: Did you try "invalidate cache and restart" or clean build?

Comment: yes, I even reinstalled but everything is the same. I found that only some of the layouts are still showing, but when I go into one of the failed layouts, the others will also fail.

Comment: I discovered the error from the material slider component